# Error for python code

Tags: python

The following code return an error `KeyError: 500`

```
def my_func(self, limit, list_type, **args):
    type2abbr = {"allcategories": "ac", "categorymembers":"cm"}
    abbr = type2abbr[list_type]
    yield abbr
if __name__ == "__main__":
    abbr = my_func(500, "categorymembers")
    print abbr
```

Output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "dater.py", line 72, in 
        bot.start()
      File "dater.py", line 56, in start
        for title, text in self.pages:
      File "dater.py", line 25, in page_generator
        for item in self.cats:
      File "/home/ceradon/api.py", line 305, in list
        abbr = type2abbr[list_type]
    KeyError: 500
```

Can anyone help me figure this out please?

Comment: If you run that code it will do nothing, because you never call the function in the code you posted.  You need to provide more info about how you are calling it (e.g., what arguments you pass).

Comment: Can you put in what your method call looks like..

Comment: Without more code, it would be hard to fully diagnose.  It looks like `list_type` is 500.  You'd have to help us understand why.

Comment: Also, it seems strange to have a function with no loop using a `yield` statement. Are you sure you want `yield` and not simply `return`?

Comment: Since it doesn't look like you're using it inside of an object, is there any reason to include `self`?

Answer (score 5):

You've implemented `my_func` as if it were a method (i.e. assuming `self`) but you are not calling it on any object.

Either you should have an object, e.g. `x.my_func(...)`, or you should remove `self,` from the argument list.